# How I can install a composer dependency via symlink?

Tags: composer-php

I have 2 php projects that share the same lib:

[image: 2 projects that use common lib]

In order for both projects to use the common lib I want for each one to do

```
composer require myorg/mylib
```

Upon each project will be the following entry to each of one in `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "myorg/proj",
    "description": "Project",
    "type": "project",
    "license": [],
    require: {
       "myorg/mylib": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

In my case I am the developer for the projects and the library. Therefore, I want instead of donwloading via packagist or satis to use the version that resides in my disk. And once I do a `git push` and my pipeline starts to run I want the `composer install` command to load it from the packagist or satis.

Is there a way to define a local path outside the `composer.json` file and just symlinks the a folder into `./vendor`?